# C++ Operator precedence and the return statement

Tags: c++, return, return-value, operator-precedence

If I do something like `return a ? b : c;` or `return a && a2 && a3;`

Could it ever be evaluated as just `return a` and then the function just returns immediately before evaluating the rest?

Comment: You **do know** that the two statements are not equivalent at all?

Comment: The `&&` operator is short circuiting, so it certainly could return without evaluating `a2` and `a3`. Don't know about the conditional though.

Comment: @MarkRansom The conditional always evaluates the condition **and** exactly one of the second and the third expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`return` is a *statement*, not an *expression*. So it can never be misinterpreted the way you think.

The statement is always of the form `return [some expression];` (and the expression is optional). The expression, if present, is evaluated first, and its value is bound to the return value of the function.

Answer (score 2):

To make this clearer I'm going to restate the question a little:

```
return a ? b() : c();

return a && a2() && a3();
```

In the first case, one of either `b` or `c` will be called but not the other.

In the second case, if `a` is false then neither `a2` nor `a3` will be called. If `a2` returns false, `a3` won't be called.

Answer (score 1):

In `return a && a2 && a3;`, if `a` is false, there's no need to evaluate the rest of the expression. The result will always be false. So `a2` and `a3` will not be evaluated. This is called "short circuiting".